# Why do SQL declare fail?

Tags: mysql, sql, declare

I have this piece of code:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NewLine CHAR(2)
    SET @NewLine = CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
END
```

When I run it in phpmyadmin, I get this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @NewLine CHAR(2) SET @NewLine = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) END' at line 2
```

I used about 2 hours on Google, without any luck. As far as I can tell, it should be the right syntax.
Someone please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flow statements like `IF`, `WHEN` and so on are only allowed in stored procedures or function in MySQL. `BEGIN` and `END` are delimiters of such statements.

Put that code in a procedure and it should work.

### Edit

Example procedure

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE PROCEDURE newline_proc(input varchar(1000))
BEGIN
  declare newline char(2);
  select CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) into newline;
  ...
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html _DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements._

Comment: That is why one can't use `DECLARE` without procedure or function either.

Comment: I have read that in the manual, and the IS begin / end as they suggest... How do I use procedure or function that would work in my case?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to use your code in a query?

Comment: Yes, the idea was to update multiple fields in a table with a replace function.

Comment: I added an example procedure.